# i dont understand why my python is running through my project folder python interpreter instead of my default location

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, directory

So i have been learning Django for a few weeks now and i dont understand why when i turned off my laptop and tried to run a simple test file it runs through the project folder instead of the default location.

What its doing - PS C:\Users\Morde\Desktop> & c:/Users/Morde/Desktop/Darts_App/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/Morde/Desktop/test.py

What i want it to do - PS C:\Users\Morde\Desktop\test.py

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: python C:\Users\Morde\Desktop\test.py if i want to run the file from the correct place i have to specify it like so.

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. this happens when i make a project and python is installed in the projects directory, VSC runs the interpreter from the default location and also the interpreter from the project locations. CTRL+Shift+P allows me to change the interpreter and running Python: Clear Workspace Interpreter Setting wipes it from the suggested list resetting it to the default and making it so any programs i run come from the original interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

This is no problem, in vscode when you use the python extension to execute a script, the terminal will display the complete command.

[image]

If you like, you can also manually enter a shorter command such as `python demo06.py` to execute the script. (*The directory needs to be correct*)

[image]

Another method is to use [*Code Runner*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner). You can [change the execution command of the python language or customize the execution command](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/blob/master/README.md#configuration).

Comment: yes but is it okay even thou i have deactivated my virtual enviorment and came out of the project folder that there are files are still running through it that are not associated with them?

Comment: This has to do with your terminal directory and the execution script. It's best to show your special example.

Comment: How can i change the directory ive had sseveral hours of googling with no luck in the matter?

Comment: Which directory are you in now? Where do you want the script to be executed? Where is the script being executed? Please describe in detail what is happening and what you want to happen?

Comment: right now im in this directory and i want the script to run from it PS C:\Users\Morde\Desktop>

Comment: Where is it executed now? Please show your mistakes?